# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. Spring boot + Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am new in both Angular and Spring Boot and I want to develop a Web application.

I followed a tutorial and now I am in a dead point.
Link to tutorial: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/22/basic-crud-angular-7-and-spring-boot-2?fbclid=IwAR2aR0Ku7oBhYM32zkxZGJXqStnRB1Lhg_K0pUO8XipZu2eiMs0ojikIY-Y

I receive this error from browser when I run the code.

I guess somehow the url doesn't match.

This is the code from Spring:

OfferController .java

```
@RestController
public class OfferController {

   @Autowired
   private OfferService offerService; 

   @CrossOrigin( origins= "http://localhost:4200" )
   @GetMapping("/offers")
   public List<Offer> getAllOffers() {
       return offerService.getAllOffers();
   }
}
```

OfferRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, String>{}
```

And code from Angular:

```
export class OfferService {

   constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

   getAll(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/offers');
   }
}
```

And the error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'offers'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'offers'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

If I'm not wrong it should work like that: when http://localhost:4200 is accessed it should return the data from http://localhost:8080/offers.

Please help me!

Comment: where is http:? you are missing http: from URL

Comment: In angular code? I added it and stil get the same error

Comment: yes in angular code

Comment: the error is still there

Comment: your URL working in browser ?

Comment: can you add your angular router?

Comment: there is issue in your router   Error: Cannot match any routes

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'offers' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'offers' at

You're trying to visit `/offers` route somewhere in your angular app, but you have not any defined like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'offers',
    component: OffersComponent
  }
];
```

There's no route `offers` in this tutorial [tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/22/basic-crud-angular-7-and-spring-boot-2?fbclid=IwAR2aR0Ku7oBhYM32zkxZGJXqStnRB1Lhg_K0pUO8XipZu2eiMs0ojikIY-Y), you've specified.

Also, after resolving this error, you'll have another one, because it's not right to use path `//localhost:8080/offers` `for http.get`. You need to specify it like:

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('http//localhost:8080/offers');
}
```

Comment: And can you tell me please where should I add this Routes?

Comment: I replaced coolCar with offer. And in Angulr car-list with offer-list

Comment: @CodauFabianValentin you can add it in client/src/app/app-routing.module.ts, but I don't think it should be added, just use valid routes specified in tutorial. More about routing is here [routing & navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: @CodauFabianValentin the error says its looking for route segment `offers` not `offer`